# Plot Python data frame over multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I have a very huge Dataframe which I want to plot. I created a smaller one for demonstration here:
How can I plot this dataframe, I would like the columns to be the x axis and sum up all the values in bars

[image]

Comment: try to sum it first (using .agg) then transpose the dataframe

Comment: Thanks, analyzeFrame = analyzeFrame.sum()   and analyzeFrame.plot(kind='bar', x='index', y='0') did the job!